# How i can add to my appname and version wirh electron-react-boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

My app after `npm run package` looks like `Electron React-4.4.0.AppImage`

How can I change it to write a new version after every build?

I checked https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/docs/packaging

But it didn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean renaming your aplication name, change content of package.json

```js
{
  "name": "electron-react-4.4.0",
  "productName": "Electron React-4.4.0",
  "description": "Electron React-4.4.0 description ...",
  ...
 }
```

to

```js
{
  "name": "your-app-name",
  "productName": "YourAppName",
  "description": "Your application description",
  ...
 }
```

After doing this you must delete node_modules and run `npm install`
and than, after `npm run package`, will our app looks like `YourAppName.AppImage`

Answer (score 2):

The version used for the package can be change in **project/release/app/package.json** not in the **project/package.json**. This has solve problem for me